# Error:(45, 36) error: cannot find symbol method findViewbyId(int)

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, calculator

Pls help. This is my first App. I deleted the findViewbyId method and noch i have a new error: Error:(45, 36) error: cannot find symbol method findViewbyId(int)

```
}
public EditText z1;
public EditText z2;
public EditText z3;
public void myBerechnen(View v) {

    EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.z1);
    EditText Feld2 = (EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.z2);
    EditText Feld3 = (EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.z3);

    Integer zahl1 = Integer.parseInt(Feld1.getText().toString());
    Integer zahl2 = Integer.parseInt(Feld2.getText().toString());

    Feld3.setText(String.valueOf(zahl1 + zahl2));
}
```

Comment: paste your code here, don't link the screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are overriding `findViewById`, remove these lines from code on first screen/Java code (always paste code and stacktrace as text!)

```
public void findViewById(int z1){


}
```

as you see `findViewById` is always `void`... this method belongs to `Activity` and you shouldn't mess with them. it work like a charm and will return you proper `View`. [doc here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))

Comment: now i have a new error. the code and the error are described on top

Comment: you are calling wrong method, use `findViewById`. with big B in "By"... Java is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) method. Just initialize the `EditText` as you are doing, it suffices.

```
EditText field1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.z1);
```